# Genymotion or similar emulator vs Chrome Dev Tools Devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, testing, mobile

I am working on responsive web layouts and am wanting to test as many devices as possible. I'm curious about the best way to do this.

Genymotion allows for easy testing between devices, but for exact pixel presentation requires a license (which is a possibility for me).

The other option seems to be Chrome's Dev Tools device section.

Is there an advantage to one over the other? What are the key differences, and what should I be aware of. Would Chrome's Dev Tools be enough, despite the differences in OS and possible browser uses on different mobile devices?